# ASP.NET Core 3 MVC : input type date not refreshing from asp-for

Tags: html, date, asp.net-core-mvc

I have

- input fields with dates only (no time)
- these field use `type=date` for date selection.
- the value is tied to the model using the asp-for attribute.

When a user incorrectly selects a FROM date that is later than the TO date:

- my action reverses the dates so they are displayed the correct way round.
- However, the HTML values maintain the previously selected values and not the newly posted, corrected values.

In effect, the asp-for is ignoring the latest value in the model.

The Model property is a DateTime and not a string and I don't use DataAnnotations in this case.

```
<input type="date" asp-for="DateFrom" 
       min="@Model.EarliestDate.ToHtmlInputDate()" 
       max="@Model.LatestDate.ToHtmlInputDate()" 
       onchange="$('form').submit();" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple fix for the issue. I'm not sure if treating the value as a string rather than a DateTime will also be a cure but that rather gets away from the fact that fundamentally it is a date.

I already have a class extension helper to get the required HTML format date so I set this string result to the VALUE of the element and this appears to work in all scenarios

```
<input type="date" value="@Model.DateFromString" asp-for="DateFrom" min="@Model.EarliestDate.ToHtmlInputDate()" max="@Model.LatestDate.ToHtmlInputDate()" onchange="$('form').submit();" class="form-control">
```